# Where can I find apparmor profiles?

Tags: apparmor

I'm interested in using apparmor to secure my laptop, and I am wondering if there is a place where I can find apparmor profiles for firefox and other desktop programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The profile for Firefox comes with the installation of Firefox. However, it is not enabled by default. To enable it, you'll have to run this command from a terminal:

`sudo aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox`

Other profiles are listed here (for 12.10):

- http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~apparmor-dev/apparmor-profiles/master/files/head:/ubuntu/12.10/

On disk they are in `/etc/apparmor.d`

You can install the additional [apparmor-profiles [image: Install apparmor-profiles]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/apparmor-profiles) package to get even more profiles. See the following documentation for more information:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor